# How to deal with NaN's when reading in a csv file in C++

Tags: c++, file-io, csv, nan

I'm reading in a csv file of time-series data into a C++ program. My data however contains
some NaN's. For example:

```
1-Jul-2010,   1.0 
2-Jul-2010,   2.0
3-Jul-2010,   NaN
4-Jul-2010,   3.0
```

To deal with this I wrote a short script in Matlab which replaces all the NaN's with 0.0 - 
I then read in the new file without the NaN's. Is there an easy way or avoiding 
this pre-processing?

Thanks!

Comment: Convert the NaNs to `0.0` while creating the file? e.g., `printf("%f", isnan(val) ? 0.0 : val);` ?

Comment: You can parse NaNs with strtof() and strtod() --- they string "NaN" (ignoring case) is handled correctly.

Comment: A NaN is NOT the same thing as 0.0!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As David Given already mentioned, you do not have to pre-process the file at all. strtof() and strtod() are both able to convert the NaN string to the NaN float/double value.

If you want to replace the values with 0.0 in your dataset, you can do so using the isnan() function.

```
if (isnan(val))
{
    val = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: On my machine (VC++) the function call: strtod("NaN",NULL) returns 0.0 (which I take to mean no valid conversion could be performed) rather then a double NaN. Am I using it correctly?

Comment: You're using it correctly and the IBM compiler returns NaN. I just tried with the MS VC++ compiler and indeed, it does return 0.0. So probably you should test yourself using stricmp() to be sure. A definition for NaN is in std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();

Comment: Thanks! I'm now using strcmp() to test for the "NaN" strings and if so then call  std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN(). But is there a function similar to strtod that will work (correctly) in MS VC++?

Comment: I don't think so. Every implementation I've seen so far uses some kind of workaround.

Comment: Just to say, this works on data from binary files too :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the result to be a float (or double) NaN - then use the stdlib strtod() function.

If you want to deal with it in your own way (set it to 0 etc) then read each line into a string first, check for NaN with strcmp() then parse the string depending on what you find - easier if NaN can only appear in one column.

Comment: Ideally I'd like the result to be a double NaN. I'll have a look at the strtod() function now.